# Submit button with 2 actions depends on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to submit button with two actions based on dropdown list that I get from MySQL. One is for updating to database and then proceed to nextpage while the other actions is to proceed to specific page. I've tried all the solution but most of them only has a few dropdown menu, mine have 40 menus.

This is my JavaScript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    //$(document).ready(function() {
      <!--To Enable button "MULA"-->
     $('#lst_respon').change(function() {
        if ($(this).find(":selected").val()!='11') {
            $('#button').attr('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
      });

      $('#lst_respon').change(function()
       {
           $('#form1').submit();
       });
}); 

function changeTextBox()
{
     var val=$('#lst_respon').val();


  if(val==='11')
  {
     $('#value').prop('disabled', true);


  }
  else{$('#value').removeAttr("disabled");}
}
</script>
```

And this is my HTML

```
    <div align="center">
    <table width="60%" border="1" class="zui-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3" align="center">Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <?php 

     $smt = $conn->prepare('select * From lookup_caraterima');
     $smt->execute();
     $data = $smt->fetchAll();

     $smt2 = $conn->prepare('select * From lookup_kodrespon');
     $smt2->execute();
     $data2 = $smt2->fetchAll();

     ?>
     <td width="253">Cara Terima</td>
     <td width="5">:</td>
     <td width="164">
     <select name="lst_cterima" id="lst_cterima">
     <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
     <option value="<? echo $row["kodterima"];?>"><? echo $row["jenis"];?> 
     </option>
     <?php endforeach ?>
     </select>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Kod Respon</td>
     <td>:</td>
     <td>
     <select name="lst_respon" id="lst_respon"   onchange="changeTextBox()">
     <?php foreach ($data2 as $row2): ?>

     <option value="<? echo $row2["kod"];?>"><? echo $row2["kod"].'-  '.$row2 ["Keterangan"];?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for ="sebab">Sebab</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="textbox" id="value" size="100" disabled</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><form name="form1" method="post"  action="main.php?load=4&SerialID=<?php echo $noSiri; ?>&month=<?php echo  $monthA;?>&year=<?php  echo $yearA;?>&tab=A">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Teruskan"  class="myButton">
    </form></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can `condition` for it,

Answer (score 0):

For an automated solution to submit a form based a dropdown selection, you could try using the `data` attribute, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form id="tester">
    <select name="test">
        <option value="best" data-instructions='<?php echo json_encode(array('action'=>'page1')); ?>'>Best</option>
        <option value="rest" data-instructions='<?php echo json_encode(array('action'=>'page2')); ?>'>Rest</option>
        <option value="guest" data-instructions='<?php echo json_encode(array('action'=>'page3')); ?>'>Guest</option>
        <option value="lest" data-instructions='<?php echo json_encode(array('action'=>'page4')); ?>'>Lest</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tester').submit(function(e) {
        // Stop form from submitting
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the select dropdown
        var thisSelect  =   $(this).find('select[name=test]');
        // Get the value
        var thisVal     =   thisSelect.val();
        // Get the options separately
        var thisOpts    =   thisSelect.children();
        // Create a holder
        var thisData    =   {};
        // Loop through the options
        $.each(thisOpts,function(k,v) {
            // Get the current value
            var currVal =   $(v).attr('value');
            // If the current value is the same as the value selected
            if(currVal == thisVal) {
                // Get the instructions from the option
                thisData    =   $(v).data('instructions');
                // Stop looping
                return false
            }
        });

        console.log(thisData);
    });
});
</script>
```

On submission, the selection will give you an object that you can use to instruct how to submit the form:

```
// thisData.action
{action: "page2"}
```